# 0's: For years between 0 to 9 AD?

Tags: writing, orthography

- For years between 30 to 39 AD you say: **30's**
- For years between 20 to 29 AD you say: **20's**
- For years between 10 to 19 AD you say: **10's**
- But what about the years between 0 to 9 AD?

  Is it **0's**?

Note: There are two entries in Wikipedia about **0s**: [**0s BC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0s_BC) (The period between 9 BC and 1 BC) and [**0s**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0s): about the first nine years of the AD/CE calendar era (AD 1–9)

Comment: I wonder if you could use the term _naughts_, but this refers to such a narrow window of time that one doesn't run across it very often. I'm not aware of any common, standard expression.

Answer (score 2):

There was no 0AD, the years went straight from 1BC to 1AD.

We don't refer to the years of the first century like this. We don't call the years 20AD-29AD as the twenties.  If we ever do refer it, we would say something like "the third decade of the first century". So 1AD -10AD would be "the first decade".  Perhaps you could use "the first decade of the common era."

We do talk about the years 1920-1929 as the "twenties", and so on. There is no generally agreed on abbreviation for the years 2000-2009 and 2010-2019. Though the "aughts" and "noughties" has been proposed for 2000-2009

Here is a [comic about this](https://xkcd.com/1849/)

Comment: But there is an article in Wikipedia about 0s BC.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero.  The wikipedia page 0sBC is part of a series of automatically generated pages one per decade.  It is chosen for consistency with other pages, rather than reflecting common usage.